# Chrome Kiosk app keep tokens

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, identity, kiosk-mode

I want to create a Kiosk application, where people log into their Google account the first time the chromebox boots. Then the credentials need to be saved, also when there is a reboot. So this chromebox will aways be logged into the same account if it is logged in once.

I am quite stuck in saving the credentials. There are two ways I have been exploring: server-side flow or client-side flow. I am focussing on client-side flow now.

What I want to do is let user login once. The access and refreshtokens should be saved on the Chromebox. If the user opens the app, it would not need to login but the app will refresh tokens itself. The user should be able to make authenticated calls to an apps  script (so we know what kiosk-user is calling).

I have been playing with this code https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/identity-api-sample/iiolfgpahklcfnhafldjkmfhkmcmdopg but I don't know the 'saving of the tokens' part. I also miss a way to refresh without user interaction.

I am not directly looking for code (there is a lot) but more a direction to work to.

Summary: Is it possible to save refreshtokens for the oauth2 flow in the kioskapp so the user has to log in only once 'ever' and where do I start for that?